# Display Shipping method chosen by customer during checkout using AJAX

Tags: magento-enterprise, ajax, shopping-cart, shipping-methods

In the one page checkout, above the progress tab in right side, we have displayed a block called Order Summary which contains the cart details [Pl refer screenshot]. There now we have to display the shipping method chosen by the customer in one page checkout as soon as they click continue button in shipping method section. I guess this can be done through AJAX like how the chosen shipping method is getting updated in the progress tab in one page checkout. Can someone help me with this?[image]

Comment: How is the order summary block being displayed currently?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? The shipping method is already shown a few lines lower.

Beside this, you can copy the `opcheckout.js` to your own theme and edit the method

```
skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:624
```

`ShippingMethod::save()` to include what you need